# How to compare text strings in a table colum matlab

Tags: matlab, compare, detection, string-comparison

If I have an N-by-1 table colum how is it possible to detect if any of the rows is identical?

Comment: What is the expected output? Just true/false?

Comment: The expected output is a logicalvector with false everywhere there is a duplicated value and an errormessage telling in which line there is a duplicated value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to determine if there are duplicate rows, you can use `unique` to do this. You can check the number of unique values in the column and compare this to the total number of elements (`numel`) in the same column

```
tf = unique(t.Column) == numel(t.Column)
```

If you want to determine *which* rows are duplicates, you can again use `unique` but use the third output and then use `accumarray` to count the number of occurrences of each value and then select those values which appear more than once.

```
[vals, ~, inds] = unique(t.Column, 'stable'); 
repeats = vals(accumarray(inds, 1) > 1);

% And to print them out:
fprintf('Duplicate value: %s\n', repeats{:})
```

If you want a logical vector of `true`/`false` for where the duplicates exist you can do something similar to that above

```
[vals, ~, inds] = unique(t.Column, 'stable');
result = ismember(inds, find(accumarray(inds, 1) > 1));
```

Or

```
[vals, ~, inds] = unique(t.Column, 'stable');
result = sum(bsxfun(@eq, inds, inds.'), 2) > 1;
```

**Update**

You can combine the two approaches above to accomplish what you want.

```
[vals, ~, inds] = unique(t.Column, 'stable'); 
repeats = vals(accumarray(inds, 1) > 1);

hasDupes = numel(repeats) > 0;

if hasDupes
    for k = 1:numel(repeats)
        fprintf('Duplicate value: %s\n', repeats{k});
        fprintf('   Found at: ');
        fprintf('%d ', find(strcmp(repeats{k}, t.Column)));
        fprintf('\n');
    end
end
```

Comment: If I use this code:
 [vals, ~, inds] = unique(t.Column, 'stable'); 
repeats = vals(accumarray(inds, 1) > 1);
 it returns, the values, which is duplicated, is it possible to write it in a for loop, so I can make matlab print an error message telling in which line there is an identical value and as output give a logical vector with 1 for each unique value, and 0 for each duplicated value?

Comment: It's almost what I need, Sorry for keep asking I'm really not good at programming, but now it gives me a logical vector with 1 everytime There is an Identical value and that is not quite what I want it to do.
I have a csv file, and then I need to detect if any of the numbers in the first colum is identical, if that's the case, I need to print an error message telling in which line there is an identical value, and then remove the duplicated, and keep the original

Comment: The only reason I can think of doing it, is using a for loop, looping over each colum and then use an if-statement, I just don't know how to write it

Comment: It is exatly what I wanted thanks for taking the time to help, I really appreciate it! 
I just have one more small request, is it possible to make it print in which lines there is a duplicated value along with the value its already printing, and making it to a logical vector instead of printing the unique values?

Comment: Last question can vals be made to a logcal vectors consisting of 1 for each unique value and 0 for each duplicated instead of printing the value?

Comment: If I use accumarray(inds, 1) == 1 it gives me a logical vector with the duplicated values, I'm bad at describing what I want matlab to do, I have an N-by-M table called T I need only to look at the first colum which is why I want it to be a logical vector consisting of each of the unique values and the only one of the duplicated, so that I could write T=T(vals,:) to get the T-table consisting only of unique values  so filtering the table from duplicated values, which also is why I want it to print a message every line consists of a duplicated value, so that I know which lines will be removed

Comment: Apologizing for keep asking, I've just been sitting with this for so long
But this:  [vals, ~, inds] = unique(t.Column, 'stable');
Gives me the first colum consisting af one of each unique value, but I need the output to be a logical full length vector with 1's  instead of the value, and 0's where there are duplicated values so that I in the end can write T=T(vals,:) and have the full table consisting of only unique values in colum 1
If you still want to help, but I'm to confusing tell me, and I'll try to explain better

Comment: `tf = ismember(inds, find(accumarray(inds, 1) == 1))`

Comment: but is it possible to make the first duplicated value, 1 instead of 0 like the rest of the duplicated?
Ex. T=[1,2,4,7,8,1,2,9]=[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1]

Comment: You could really figure this out for yourself if you play with the intermediate variables. Use the second output of `unique`: `[~, inds] = unique(t.Column, 'stable'); newtable = t(inds,:)`

Comment: Thanks for your help!